# Storage issue when trying to load docker image on centos7

Tags: docker, unix

Initially I've increased the volume size of "/dev/mapper/rhel-var" from 2g to 9g.

When trying to load docker image I get this error:
[image]

Filesistem:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem                      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                        3.9G  4.0K  3.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs                           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                           3.9G  9.0M  3.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/rhel-root            50G  8.8G   42G  18% /
/dev/sda1                      1014M  150M  865M  15% /boot
/dev/mapper/rhel-home            21G   13G  7.9G  62% /home
/dev/mapper/rhel-tmp            5.0G   35M  5.0G   1% /tmp
/dev/mapper/rhel-var            9.0G  152M  8.9G   2% /var
/dev/mapper/rhel-var_log        9.0G   53M  9.0G   1% /var/log
/dev/mapper/rhel-var_tmp        2.0G   74M  2.0G   4% /var/tmp
/dev/mapper/rhel-var_log_audit  3.0G  2.9G  105M  97% /var/log/audit
tmpfs                           783M     0  783M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Is it any other volume that needs aditional storage space?

**Docker image (I mean the .tar file) space is around 4.8G**

```
$ ll
total 4634988
-rwxr-x---. 1 admin admin 4746224640 Oct 28 14:51 daas2.tar*
```

Thanks
Cosmin

Later edit:
Got this crash of the machine

```
$ sudo docker image load -i daas2.tar
7ea4455e747e: Loading layer [==================================================>]  80.31MB/80.31MB
b3b741e72ab9: Loading layer [==================================================>]  46.68MB/46.68MB
9c79dfcaa270: Loading layer [==================================================>]  3.584kB/3.584kB
2335e0a013ff: Loading layer [==================================================>]  4.608kB/4.608kB
5dabc97cd0ea: Loading layer [======================>                            ]  812.7MB/1.772GB

Remote side unexpectedly closed network connection

────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

Session stopped
    - Press <return> to exit tab
    - Press R to restart session
    - Press S to save terminal output to file
h of the machine:
```

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Include the text itself in your question, formatted as a code sample.

Comment: I am unable right now to copy the text... The machine was reverted... I have just these screenshots... Sorry

Comment: I've updated with what I could...

Comment: Start loading it, while it is happening, open a second terminal, run `df` repeatedly and observe which usage chagnes over time.

Comment: Could be that the .tar is decompressed in /tmp (or some other mount point without enough space) before being added as an image? That would explain the system crash as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was:

```
/dev/mapper/rhel-var_log_audit  3.0G  2.9G  105M  97% /var/log/audit
```

I've check according to "Start loading it, while it is happening, open a second terminal, run df repeatedly and observe which usage chagnes over time. –
KamilCuk
Oct 28 at 17:14"

and this volume went full then crash.

Conclusion:
When loading a docker image here is where it writes things, at least in:

```
/var/lib/docker
/var/run/docker
/var/log/audit
```

I've cleared the /var/log/audit and it worked.

Thanks!